# Import "global" function to TypeScript module

Tags: function, typescript, math, import, module

I'm making a "math" module, which has more functions than the default "Math", however i want to include/inherit some of the functions from Math. is there a way of doing this in TypeScript?

In javascript it would look like this

```
var math = {
    max: Math.max;
}
```

I want to avoid doing this

```
export module math {
  export function Max(...values: number[]): number {
    return Math.max.apply(null, values);
  }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this (which doesn't work ofc.)

```
export module math {
  import { max } from Math;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible

```
export const math = {
    max: Math.max;
    otherMethod: function otherMethod() {/*TODO: additional code*/};
}
```

Comment: I hope you're right, have you tested it? because I still get errors :( it fails to build, and i have highligting errors on Math in visual studio saying "(TS) String literal expected."

Comment: the edited example gives me "(TS) unused label" error for "max:" :(

Comment: No need "module" keyword in ts, export variables and classes or interfaces instead : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html